# Query with nested GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to apply two different angle of query in one statement. I have table of customers with information of city and number of products they bought as

```
    c_id,city,no_products
    1, city1,0
    2, city2,20
    3, city2,80
    4,city1,10
```

The summary I am looking for is grouped by city as well as grouped by no_products range including 0 counts for range which is not existed in table. Ranges are predefined as grpA = no_products between 0 to 50,grpB = no_products between 51 to 100.

```
city,total_customers,grpA,grpB
city1,2,2,0
city2,2,1,1
```

So as above I want to nested the `select City,count(*) as city_customer_count from C_tbl group by City`

with

```
select t.range as [GROUPS], count(*) as [number of customers]
from (
  select case  
    when no_products between 0 and 20 then N'GROUPC'
    when no_products between 21 and 80 then N'GROUPB'
    when no_products > 80 then N'GROUPA'
     end as range
  from C_tbl) t
group by t.range
```

However the above query also not consider 0 counts for not existed range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
SELECT city,
       COUNT(*) AS total_customers,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN no_products BETWEEN 0 AND 50 THEN 1 END) AS grpA,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN no_products BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN 1 END) AS grpB
FROM C_tbl
GROUP BY city
```

Output:

```
city    total_customers     grpA    grpB
city1   2                   2       0
city2   2                   1       1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e2cb33/1)